# Cant understand why my phone blocks bluetooth permission request

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions, app-inventor

I'm tring to make an app (MIT APP INVENTOR) that will use bluetooth to connect to an esp32 cam.
My problem is that I use this code and I get
`Error 908:The permission BLUETOOTH_CONNECT has been denied. Please enable it in the Settings app.`

```
    when Screen1.Initialize
        call Screen1.AskForPermission
                     permissionName "BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"

    when Screen1.PermissionGranted
        if get(permissionName) = "BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"
            call Screen1.AskForPermission
                         permissionName "BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
```

For context i use this app on a Galaxy S22, and the guy that I got this code from is also using this phone and he said that i need to ask for location permission for some reason and it worked for him(youtube comment section)
I tried to search it, but i only find "mit app inventor is already doing that for you" it is not for me or that i need to add some lines in AndroidManifest.xml, but i cant find that without a separeted program and i only found shady ones for some reason.

I think I cant do more to the code and it is something about my phone or android 13 permission system, also if i go in Settings > Apps > my app > permission there is not bluetooth permission only location, music, photos and notifications
I`m using the extension BluetoothLE
[image: the blocks of code from mit app inventor]

Comment: On older phones you need different Bluetooth and additional location permissions for Bluetooth scanning. On newer Android versions you need totally different Bluetooth permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the beta version of the BLE extension.  You can find it here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/beta-version-of-ble-extension-for-android-12-permission-changes/77286?u=taifun. See also the other comments in that thread.